# How to call didSet without changing property value

Tags: swift, properties, didset

I need the code in `didSet` to be executed without changing the property's value.

Coming from Objective-C recently, there doesn't seem to be a `setMyProperty()`.

So I tried:

```
self.myProperty = self.myProperty
```

which result in error `Assigning a property to itself`.

Because `myProperty` happens to be `CGFloat`, I could do:

```
self.myProperty += 0.0
```

which does trigger `didSet` and does not affect the value, but it doesn't show what I mean to do here.

Is there a way to call `didSet` in a more clear/direct way?

Comment: In my opinion `didSet` as it name indicates, means that the property has been set to a value, so trying to execute didSet without changing the value doesn't make sense and it makes your code unclear.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try this:

```
self.myProperty = { self.myProperty }()
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
struct MyStruct {
    var myProperty: CGFloat {
        didSet {
            myFunc()
        }
    }

    func myFunc() { ... }
}
```

Here `myFunc` will be called when `myProperty` is set. You can also call `myFunc` directly, such as in the situation you required `didSet` to be called.

Comment: I thought about this, but continued looking for a 'native' Swift construction. My `didSet` is just two lines so I didn't want to just add a function for that.

Answer (score 0):

**didSet** is called after the property value has already been changed. If you want to revert it to it's previous value(so having the same effect as not changing the property's value), you need to assign it 'oldValue' property. Please take note that **oldValue** is not a variable defined by you, it comes predefined.

```
var myProperty: CGFloat {
    didSet {
        myProperty = oldValue
    }
}
```

Comment: I do want a change in most cases, but sometimes I just need didSet to execute without change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tuple Swift 3

```
var myProperty : (CGFloat,Bool) = (0.0, false){

            didSet {
                if myProperty.1 {

               myProperty = (0.0, false) // or (oldValue.0, false)

                    //code.....
                }else{

                    // code.....
                }
            }


        }

    myProperty = (1.0, true)

    print(myProperty.0) //print 0.0

    myProperty = (1.0, false)

    print(myProperty.0) //print 1.0

    myProperty = (11.0, true)

    print(myProperty.0) //print 0.0
```

Comment: It's technically interesting. It would require a change to all the code that uses this property; not a good thing.  I'll up two of your other answers (giving you 20 points) as thanks for the effort and idea.